# How to keep imageview inside UIView when moving imageview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

I have an UIView inside main view controller which contain 1 imageview.i moved imageview with this method.

```
 - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
   if (aTouch.view == self.sub_View) {
    CGPoint location = [aTouch locationInView:self.sub_View];
    CGPoint previousLocation = [aTouch previousLocationInView:self.sub_View];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.imageView.frame, (location.x - previousLocation.x), (location.y - previousLocation.y));
    }
}
```

Imageview move perfect. But i have to keep imageview inside UIView when i moved. Problem with this code is when i move imageview it is also moved outside UIView. I have to keep imageview inside UIView and movable only inside UIView.
Please help me to solve this. How to set boundary for imageview so it is movable only inside UIView.

Comment: what is self.sub_View

Comment: it is a UIview on main view which contain imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
   if (aTouch.view == self.sub_View) {
    CGPoint location = [aTouch locationInView:self.sub_View];
    CGPoint previousLocation = [aTouch previousLocationInView:self.sub_View];
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset(self.imageView.frame, (location.x - previousLocation.x), (location.y - previousLocation.y));
    if(newFrame.origin.x < 0)
         newFrame.origin.x = 0;
    if(newFrame.origin.y < 0)
         newFrame.origin.y = 0;
    if(newFrame.origin.x + newFrame.size.width > self.frame.size.width)
         newFrame.origin.x = self.frame.size.width - self.imageView.frame.size.width;
    if(newFrame.origin.y + newFrame.size.height > self.frame.size.height)
         newFrame.origin.y = self.frame.size.height - self.imageView.frame.size.height;

    self.imageView.frame = newFrame;

    }
}
```

Comment: now movement is inside Uiview but when i zoom  imageview it will reset imagevuew frame and as you scroll it will hide image..

Comment: what you mean by self.frame.size.width?

Answer (score 0):

a) You can set the `clipsToBounds` property of your `UIView` to `YES`

b) You can use the fallowing code for moving your `UIImageView`

```
self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(MAX(0.0, MIN(location.x - previousLocation.x, self.sub_View.bounds.size.width)), MAX(0.0, MIN(location.y - previousLocation.y, self.sub_View.bounds.size.height)));
```

Comment: it keep imageview on upper left corner after 1st move after that imageview stay there.